# Jquery text scroller from bottom to top

Tags: jquery

Want a  text scroller which should move from bottom to top and on mouseover it should stop. Main requirement is it should work on IE7 and IE8. Pls find this URL

http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Endless-Div-Scroll-Plugin.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
$("#s2").endlessScroll({
width: '700px', // Desired div's width.
height: '26px', // Desired div's height.
steps: -2, // pixel step for the <a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Scroll/">scrolling</a>, also controls the direction, a negatif value (left), a positive value (right).
speed: 40, // animation speed, from 0 (quicker) to infinite (slower).
mousestop: false }); //if set to true the scrolling stops when the mouse is over the div.
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should provide more details and maybe a piece of code of what you have done so far. I managed to do this with some marquee before.

```
<marquee behavior="slide" direction="left">Your slide-in text goes here</marquee>
```

on mouse over tell it to "stop"

Comment: please find the above URL and i need to customize that text scroller from top to bottom

Comment: never used the "endlessScroll" api... but how about you register a function to the moseover and change the steps to '2' instead of '-2' ?